# Jquery: get for image with id like and class like

Tags: jquery, sorting

I want to get an image by id like and class like, I have done this but can't get it to work:

```
 Recency<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox order-by" id="order_dateDESC"/>   
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="order-by order-by-img" id="order_dateASC" src="icons/up-arrow.png" width="8" height="7" /></a>       
<a href="javascript:void(0)">   
<img  class="order-by order-by-img desc" id="order_dateDESC" src="icons/down-arrow.png" width="8" height="7" /></a>

Popularity<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox order-by" id="order_popDESC"/>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img class="order-by order-by-img" id="order_popASC" src="icons/up-arrow.png" width="8" height="7" /></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
<img  class="order-by order-by-img desc" id="order_popDESC" src="icons/down-arrow.png" width="8" height="7" /></a>

<script>
 $('.order-by-img [id^="'+order_by.substring(0, 9)+'"]').toggle() ;
</script>
```

When you click the checkbox it sorts by default ordering. When you click the down or up arrow it should sort accordingly, the checkbox is working. What I can't manage is to toggle the images. How can I do the toggling.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space :

```
$('.order-by-img[id^="'+order_by.substring(0, 9)+'"]').toggle() ;
```

The space asks for a descendant.